# p:dataTable with p:cellEditor tab behaviour

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, tablecelleditor

I have the follwing datatable structure:

```
<p:dataTable editable="true" editMode="cell"..>

<p:column headerText="value_1">
  <p:cellEditor>
      <f:facet name="output">
         <h:outputText ...
      </f:facet>
      <f:facet name="input">
         <p:inputText ....
      </f:facet>
  </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="value_2">
  <p:cellEditor>
      <f:facet name="output">
         <h:outputText ...
      </f:facet>
      <f:facet name="input">
         <p:inputText ....
      </f:facet>
  </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="action">
  <p:commandButton tabindex="-1"...
</p:column>
```

The problem is that the last column breaks the tab-navigation. I can tab from column1 to column2 but cannot reach the next row.
When I remove the last column everything works as expected. I want a tab-behaviour like this:

row1_column1 -> row1_column2 -> row2_column1 -> row2_column2 -> ....

I also tried to remove `tabindex="-1"` and use a `p:cellEditor` in the third column, but the behaviour stays the same, I can only tab in row1.
What am I missing?

I'm using Primefaces version 6.0

Comment: I think the real answer to this question is https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1745 (which is not resolved), but that is not a solution for you but an explanation. A solution for me would be to complex (relatively) to create and I do not want to create this as answer yet... (and please post version info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PrimeFaces data table cell editor tab behavior is implemented [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js#L2243):

```
2243    tabCell: function(cell, forward) {
2244        var targetCell = forward ? cell.next() : cell.prev();
2245        if(targetCell.length == 0) {
2246            var tabRow = forward ? cell.parent().next() : cell.parent().prev();
2247            targetCell = forward ? tabRow.children('td.ui-editable-column:first') : tabRow.children('td.ui-editable-column:last');
2248        }
2249
2250        this.showCellEditor(targetCell);
2251    },
```

Check line 2244. The `next()` and `prev()` calls do not check whether it's a `.ui-editable-column`. So it basically blindly tabs into any column even if it doesn't contain a `<p:cellEditor>`.

We thus want to fix exactly that part to check for `.ui-editable-column`. Put the below code in a JS file.

```
if (PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable) {
    PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable = PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.extend({
        tabCell: function(cell, forward) {
            var targetCell = forward ? cell.next('td.ui-editable-column') : cell.prev('td.ui-editable-column');
            if(targetCell.length == 0) {
                var tabRow = forward ? cell.parent().next() : cell.parent().prev();
                targetCell = forward ? tabRow.children('td.ui-editable-column:first') : tabRow.children('td.ui-editable-column:last');
            }

            this.showCellEditor(targetCell);
        }
    });
}
```

Make sure that this JS file is loaded *after* PrimeFaces own JS. The best place for that is shown below:

```
<h:head>
    ...
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputScript name="primefaces-patches.js" target="head" />
    ...
</h:body>
```

#### See also:

- [MonkeyPatching: PrimeFaces widgets extend/override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594082/monkeypatching-primefaces-widgets-extend-override)
- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)