# JSF Primefaces many lines quote

Tags: primefaces, quill

Primefaces 6.1 new Text Editor component is using QuillJS 1.22 for rich text editing. Unfortunately this editor is parsing html code in his own way.
When I put this in backing bean variable:

```
<p>a<br>a<br>a</p>
```

I end up with this:

```
<p>a</p>
<p><br></p>
<p>a</p>
<p><br></p>
<p>a</p>
```

Is there option to insert directly html code to an QuillJS editor from Primefaces?

Comment: Try 'shift-enter' in the editor

Comment: It's now editor problem. It's problem of generated html code by deployed application.

Comment: 'Now' or 'not' an editor problem?

Comment: Not* It seems to be a QuillJS problem. QuillJS is importing text from backing bean variable and formatting it in his way. I want to just attach html code to text already in editor.

Comment: What does the content you pass to it from the backingbean look like... it is impossible to reproduce in this way. Please make a [mcve]

Comment: Sure there are not 'newline' chars in there?

Comment: 100% sure. I am working now on solution by inserting this value by js script of texteditor

Comment: So you debugged where the html tags are added?

Comment: Actually I can override or add new js functions by widgetVar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594082/monkeypatching-primefaces-widgets-extend-override and than invoke them by `RequestContext`. Unfortunately in quilljs we can't just past html code without parsing so I have to get back to old editor tag

Answer (score -2):

We can add new function to js code of component:

```
if(PrimeFaces.widget.TextEditor){
    PrimeFaces.widget.TextEditor = PrimeFaces.widget.TextEditor.extend({
        insertText: function (text){
            this.editor.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(0, text);
        }
    });
}
```

but there is no option to put unparsed html code to QuillJS 1.22. For now I had to go back to old Editor component, which support inserting unparsed html code.

Comment: So your answer does not work? Then it is not an answer and better removed.

Comment: So whole question should be removed, but when someone will search for same problem this answer will tell him that for now it is not possible.

Comment: Then explicitly change it... and add version info on which PrimeFaces version it applies to