yearNavigator in p:datePicker appears as spinner instead of dropdown
Since PrimeFaces 14: yearNavigator in datePicker appears as spinner instead of a dropdown.
This is totally complicated when you have to (in a list of 100 years) get to 1917 when you are in 2024 and you have to click those small arrows to go down one by one.
Could be possible to replace the spinner for the old dropdown? just the same as the monthNavigator?
No option to choose how to display the yearNavigator as in PrimeFaces, just the same as the monthNavigator

This feature was added for the same reason you are complaining about. With a list of 100 years you would need to scroll way down if you would need a year at the bottom of that list. You even may need to do this multiple times, depending on the shown range in the dropdown. Therefor we changed the input to type="number" (which is rendered with spinning buttons by your browser). You can simply enter the year you would need using the keyboard. This was changed with issue https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/8950
I guess it's debatable whether that should be a toggleable feature. As you already opened an issue for it, please keep your eye on https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/12097

Unless you can change it's behavior by editing styles of .ui-datepicker-year component (check to be sure) - I doubt it is possible. You might want to bypass this "feature" by nesting your self made year picker inside navigator without default year picker, but it's a lot of work.
I would post is as comment but I can't do it yet, sorry for this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594082/monkeypatching-primefaces-widgets-extend-override
